# Can I use my sole proprietorship EIN on the W9 for my single-member LLC?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, ein

The IRS [says](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/single-member-limited-liability-companies)

> For federal income tax purposes, a single-member LLC classified as a disregarded entity generally must use the owner's social security number (SSN) or employer identification number (EIN) for all information returns and reporting related to income tax. For example, if a disregarded entity LLC that is owned by an individual is required to provide a Form W-9, Request for Taxpayer Identification Number (TIN) and Certification, the W-9 should provide the owner’s SSN or EIN, not the LLC’s EIN.

I have a disregarded entity LLC, and I got it an EIN to open a bank account, but the above says I shouldn't use the LLC's EIN on the W-9.

However, I also have another EIN because I needed it to open a solo 401k as a sole proprietorship (before I started my LLC).  Can I use my sole proprietor EIN instead of my SSN on my LLC's W9?

My motivation is to give out my SSN less, since it's hard to change and can be used to steal my identity.

Comment: The last 10 words are "provide the owner’s SSN or EIN, not the LLC’s EIN".  So use your EIN.

Comment: Write that as an answer, and I'll accept it.